# How can I generate this exact table?

Tags: output-formatting

[image]

The TableForm[] is a trig table which shows sine, cosine and tangent values for integer angles from 0 degrees to 90 degrees in steps of 3 degrees.

I want to recreate the exact same table using Mathematica. I need to use TableForm[].

This is what I have so far:

```
TeXForm@TableForm[
  Select[
   Flatten[
    Table[
     {angle, sine, cosine, tangent},
     {angle, 0, 90, 3},
     {sine, N[Sin[0 Degree], 4], N[Sin[90 Degree], 4], angle},
     {cosine, N[Cos[0 Degree], 4], N[Cos[90 Degree], 4], angle},
     {tangent, N[Tan[0 Degree], 4], N[Tan[90 Degree], 4], angle}
     ],
    1
    ],
   IntegerQ[#[[3]]] && GCD[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == 1 &
   ]
  ]
```

I'm trying to manipulate code that I used for making another table so the last line:

```
IntegerQ[#[[3]]] && GCD[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == 1 &
```

Might be completely irrelevant. For the lines that show sine, cosine and tangent, I tried to start at 0 degrees, show 4 numbers (leading zeros don't count hence the values for angle 3 for sine and tangent), go up to 90 degrees, and I want it to go up in increments of 3 degrees.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
columnheadings = {"angle", "sine", "cosine", "tangent"};
vals = Table[{angle, N[Sin[angle Degree], 4], N[Cos[angle Degree], 4],
     N[Tan[angle Degree], 4]}, {angle, 0 , 90, 3}];

t=TableForm[vals, TableHeadings -> {None, columnheadings}]
```

[image]

```
TeXForm[t]
```

$\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{angle} & \text{sine} & \text{cosine} & \text{tangent} \\
 0 & 0 & 1.000 & 0 \\
 3 & 0.05234 & 0.9986 & 0.05241 \\
 6 & 0.1045 & 0.9945 & 0.1051 \\
 9 & 0.1564 & 0.9877 & 0.1584 \\
 12 & 0.2079 & 0.9781 & 0.2126 \\
 15 & 0.2588 & 0.9659 & 0.2679 \\
 18 & 0.3090 & 0.9511 & 0.3249 \\
 21 & 0.3584 & 0.9336 & 0.3839 \\
 24 & 0.4067 & 0.9135 & 0.4452 \\
 27 & 0.4540 & 0.8910 & 0.5095 \\
 30 & 0.5000 & 0.8660 & 0.5774 \\
 33 & 0.5446 & 0.8387 & 0.6494 \\
 36 & 0.5878 & 0.8090 & 0.7265 \\
 39 & 0.6293 & 0.7771 & 0.8098 \\
 42 & 0.6691 & 0.7431 & 0.9004 \\
 45 & 0.7071 & 0.7071 & 1.000 \\
 48 & 0.7431 & 0.6691 & 1.111 \\
 51 & 0.7771 & 0.6293 & 1.235 \\
 54 & 0.8090 & 0.5878 & 1.376 \\
 57 & 0.8387 & 0.5446 & 1.540 \\
 60 & 0.8660 & 0.5000 & 1.732 \\
 63 & 0.8910 & 0.4540 & 1.963 \\
 66 & 0.9135 & 0.4067 & 2.246 \\
 69 & 0.9336 & 0.3584 & 2.605 \\
 72 & 0.9511 & 0.3090 & 3.078 \\
 75 & 0.9659 & 0.2588 & 3.732 \\
 78 & 0.9781 & 0.2079 & 4.705 \\
 81 & 0.9877 & 0.1564 & 6.314 \\
 84 & 0.9945 & 0.1045 & 9.514 \\
 87 & 0.9986 & 0.05234 & 19.08 \\
 90 & 1.000 & 0 & \text{ComplexInfinity} \\
\end{array} $

An alternative with dividing lines:

```
tt = Grid[Join[{columnheadings}, vals], 
  Dividers -> {All, {True, True, False}}, Frame -> True, 
  Spacings -> {1, .5}]
```

[image]

```
TeXForm[tt]
```

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{angle} & \text{sine} & \text{cosine} & \text{tangent} \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & 1.000 & 0 \\
 3 & 0.05234 & 0.9986 & 0.05241 \\
 6 & 0.1045 & 0.9945 & 0.1051 \\
 9 & 0.1564 & 0.9877 & 0.1584 \\
 12 & 0.2079 & 0.9781 & 0.2126 \\
 15 & 0.2588 & 0.9659 & 0.2679 \\
 18 & 0.3090 & 0.9511 & 0.3249 \\
 21 & 0.3584 & 0.9336 & 0.3839 \\
 24 & 0.4067 & 0.9135 & 0.4452 \\
 27 & 0.4540 & 0.8910 & 0.5095 \\
 30 & 0.5000 & 0.8660 & 0.5774 \\
 33 & 0.5446 & 0.8387 & 0.6494 \\
 36 & 0.5878 & 0.8090 & 0.7265 \\
 39 & 0.6293 & 0.7771 & 0.8098 \\
 42 & 0.6691 & 0.7431 & 0.9004 \\
 45 & 0.7071 & 0.7071 & 1.000 \\
 48 & 0.7431 & 0.6691 & 1.111 \\
 51 & 0.7771 & 0.6293 & 1.235 \\
 54 & 0.8090 & 0.5878 & 1.376 \\
 57 & 0.8387 & 0.5446 & 1.540 \\
 60 & 0.8660 & 0.5000 & 1.732 \\
 63 & 0.8910 & 0.4540 & 1.963 \\
 66 & 0.9135 & 0.4067 & 2.246 \\
 69 & 0.9336 & 0.3584 & 2.605 \\
 72 & 0.9511 & 0.3090 & 3.078 \\
 75 & 0.9659 & 0.2588 & 3.732 \\
 78 & 0.9781 & 0.2079 & 4.705 \\
 81 & 0.9877 & 0.1564 & 6.314 \\
 84 & 0.9945 & 0.1045 & 9.514 \\
 87 & 0.9986 & 0.05234 & 19.08 \\
 90 & 1.000 & 0 & \text{ComplexInfinity} \\
\end{array}$

Another option would be to adjust the formatting in TeX.

Comment: thank you so much!! this is a really dumb question but what about the borders and column bars? is there a way i can add it?

Comment: also how can i make it show 4 digits like for last value under sine column making it 1.000. and taking away the period in the first value under sine column?

Comment: @user130306 Oh sorry, to show 4 digits you can use, for example, `N[Sin[angle Degree], 4]` as you had it.

Comment: @user130306 Regarding borders/divider lines - you can make a table with full control over grid lines using `Grid`; I will update the answer accordingly. However, I'm not sure how it carries over in TeXForm.

Answer (score 2):

As in your image, this gives four significant digits except integers are kept exact.

```
nf = NumberForm[N@#, {6, 4 - Ceiling@Log10[N@#]}] &;

Off[NumberForm::iprf]

Framed[Grid[
  Prepend[
   Table[
      {a, Sin[a Degree], Cos[a Degree], Tan[a Degree]},
      {a, 0, 90, 3}] /.
     x_?(NumericQ[N[#]] && Not[IntegerQ[#]] &) :> nf[x],
   {"angle", "sine", "cosine", "tangent"}],
  Dividers -> {All, {False, True}}],
 FrameStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]